# Why does this error happen when I try to add firebase to my Android project?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

I try to use firebase here 
     my code
                https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcbeT.png

```
           // I tried these solution and doesn't work 

   //  1. remove the

            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0'
        //    and add only

            implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

    //      2.
            allprojects {
              repositories {
               google()
               maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
             }
            }
```

Comment: Update your dependencies.

Answer (score 3):

Add the following dependency to your app gradle (update according to your need):

> implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:x.x.x'

Just checked your provided screenshot there is **extra** `:15.0.0` at the end of this line **remove** this and you are good to go:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By Default, the latest versions of `Android Studio` will add a dependency with two "core values" as you've said above.

Make sure before you sync, you've one core e.g

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
```

and not

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0:16.0.1'
```